# Using custom materials in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using a Ar marker in my simulation. For this I use a custom material which loads a marker (pattHiro). But the materials are in /opt/ and need "shadow_receiver.program" How can I use a custom file which can be stored with the model in /home/work? (with relative paths)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1108/using-custom-materials-in-gazebo/) by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-29**:
are you running gazebo standalone, fuerte or groovy?

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-01-29**:
Gazebo in fuerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I originally wrote this "Have you tried specifying absolute paths in the SDF  tags?" and it's wrong. Chalk it up to a mental lapse.

Here is some information on : http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Uri

A uri is relative to a Gazebo environment variable. For example if `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/tmp`, then a `<uri>model://my_model</uri>` tells Gazebo to find this directory `/tmp/my_model`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-01-30**:
No, But it this documented somewhere? I could not find it in the sdf reference. For portablility relative paths would be even better, is this possible? Also in ROS Gazebo version the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` does not exist. I would be possible to add it but that would again be a custom solution, limiting portability.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-08**:
Relative paths are not portable, they are dependent on where gazebo is run. This varies from user to user and machine to machine. More uri documentation is here: http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.3.html (do a find on uri).